# pandas drop na dropping all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop that reads in excel sheets and have a line to drop rows. However it looks like it is dropping all rows. `sheet.dropna(inplace=True)` is dropping all records. Does anyone know why this is? Why I remove this line from my loop, all records are imported. Is it because one of my columns are completely blank with no values?

```
def read_excel_sheets(xls_path):
   """Read all sheets of an Excel workbook and return a single DataFrame"""
   print(f'Loading {xls_path} into pandas')
   xl = pd.ExcelFile(xls_path)
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   for idx, name in enumerate(xl.sheet_names):
        print(f'Reading sheet #{idx+1}: {name}')
        sheet = xl.parse(name, header=None, dtype=str, ignore_index=True)
        # Drop Empty Rows
        sheet.dropna(inplace=True)
        # Drop Empty Columns
        sheet.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
        # Add sheet name as column
        sheet['sheet'] = name.split(" ")[-1]
        # Get number of Rows from Sheet importd
        print(f'Rows with data Imported: {len(sheet):,}')
        # Appending Data
        if len(df.columns) >= len(sheet.columns):
            df = df.append(sheet, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
        else:
            df = sheet.append(df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
        del sheet
   return df
```

sample of my data:

[image]

Comment: "Col 3" is entirely empty, so I would expect all rows to be dropped.

Comment: Cf documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html. Defaults are row-based drops with any NA in that row dropping the column. Because col 3 is empty, all rows are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

when you use <<sheet.dropna(inplace=True)>> this means If any NA values are present, drop that row. in your data set there is at least one NA value for each row.
if you want to delete a row which is completely empty use <<sheet.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)>>